# Using Json.net to deserialize to any unkown type works for objects but not value types

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

I've implemented a Json Serializer based on Json.net to accept any object type and serialize it (for placement into my cache)

The cache interface doesn't allow me to speficy the type, so When I retrieve from the cache I need to dynamically create the type from the meta information.

Which works well for objects, the problem I am now facing is that i doesn't work for value types, I will get an exception saying something along the lines of `cannot cast JValue to JObject`.

My question is how can I cater for value types as well as object types? It would be great if there was a TryParse for a JObject, which I could write myself, but feel like I am going down a rabbit hole?

What is the best way to achieve this?

My code is as follows, settings for Json.net:

```
_settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
                NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
                DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc,
                TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All
            };

_settings.Converters.Add(new StringEnumConverter());
```

The set function (serialize):

```
public void Put(string cacheKey, object toBeCached, TimeSpan cacheDuration)
        {
            _cache.Set(cacheKey, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(toBeCached, _settings), cacheDuration);
        }
```

And the get (deserialize):

```
 public object Get(string cacheKey)
    {
        try
        {
            var value = _cache.Get(cacheKey);

            if (!value.HasValue)
            {
                return null;
            }

            var jobject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(value);
            var typeName = jobject?["$type"].ToString();

            if (typeName == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            var type = Type.GetType(typeName);
            return jobject.ToObject(type);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // Todo
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to parse to a [`JToken`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken.htm) rather than a `JObject`, then check to see if the returned type is a [`JValue`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JValue.htm) containing a JSON primitive:

```
public static object Get(string value)
{
    var jToken = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JToken>(value);
    if (jToken == null)
        return null;
    else if (jToken is JValue)
    {
        return ((JValue)jToken).Value;
    }
    else
    {
        if (jToken["$type"] == null)
            return null;
        // Use the same serializer settings as used during serialization.
        // Ideally with a proper SerializationBinder that sanitizes incoming types as suggested
        // in https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_TypeNameHandling.htm
        var _settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
            NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
            DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc,
            TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All,
            Converters = { new StringEnumConverter() },
            //SerializationBinder = new SafeSerializationBinder(),
        };
        // Since the JSON contains a $type parameter and TypeNameHandling is enabled, if we deserialize 
        // to type object the $type information will be used to determine the actual type, using Json.NET's
        // serialization binder: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeSerializationBinder.htm
        return jToken.ToObject(typeof(object), JsonSerializer.CreateDefault(_settings));
    }
}
```

Note, however, that type information for  primitives will not get precisely round-tripped:

- Integers will be returned as a `long` (or a `BigInteger` if larger than [`long.MaxValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int64.maxvalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).
- Floating point values will be returned as a `double` or a `decimal`, depending upon the setting of [`JsonSerializerSettings.FloatParseHandling`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_FloatParseHandling.htm) -- either [`FloatParseHandling.Double`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_FloatParseHandling.htm) or [`FloatParseHandling.Decimal`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_FloatParseHandling.htm).
- JSON strings that "look like" dates will get converted to `DateTime`, `DateTimeOffset`, or left as strings, depending on the setting [`JsonSerializerSettings.DateParseHandling`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_DateParseHandling.htm).
- `enum` names will be converted to strings.

If you need to round-trip type information for primitives, consider using `TypeWrapper<T>` from [Deserialize specific enum into system.enum in Json.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31351262/deserialize-specific-enum-into-system-enum-in-json-net) to encapsulate your root objects.

Finally, if there is any chance you might be deserializing untrusted JSON (and if you are deserializing from a file or from the internet then you certainly are), please note the following caution from the [Json.NET documentation](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_TypeNameHandling.htm):

> TypeNameHandling should be used with caution when your application deserializes JSON from an external source. **Incoming types should be validated with a custom [SerializationBinder](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializer_SerializationBinder.htm) when deserializing with a value other than None.**

For a discussion of why this may be necessary, see [TypeNameHandling caution in Newtonsoft Json](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39565954/3744182), [How to configure Json.NET to create a vulnerable web API](https://www.alphabot.com/security/blog/2017/net/How-to-configure-Json.NET-to-create-a-vulnerable-web-API.html), and Alvaro Muñoz & Oleksandr Mirosh's blackhat paper https://www.blackhat.com/docs/us-17/thursday/us-17-Munoz-Friday-The-13th-JSON-Attacks-wp.pdf

Comment: This is one of the most vulnerable JSON deserializers I have ever seen. You're allowing an attacker to deserialize literally ANY type, including ones with side-effecting constructors. At least use a switch and narrow the options down to relevant ones. Not quite as bad as de-pickling, but damn.

Comment: @cormacrelf - you know, you have a point.  I just answered the precise question of *I am deserializing JSON with a polymorphic `$type` property.  How can I extend that to deserialize primitive values*?  without considering whether this was a good idea in the first place.  The only defense is that the application **itself**, not some external caller, is serializing the objects into its cache.  But at least a link to [TypeNameHandling caution in Newtonsoft Json](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39565954/3744182) would be in order.  I've already updated some of my answers to link to it.

Comment: Good good. I was a bit harsh but these things get copy-pasted around (268 views on this question), it's got to be clear!

Comment: Much better answer. Took a zipline straight to best practice reference.