# Json.NET - Preserve double/decimal datatypes

Tags: c#, json.net, decimal

I have reduced our real-world case to a simpler one (which may now look a bit constructed, yet hopefully easier to comprehend). Basically we have an loosely typed array `object[]` which may contain a mixture of `decimal` and `double` values as well as all kinds of other objects (strings, dates, other primitives, nested arrays, custom classes, etc). We want to use Json.NET for transferring such array to a remote machine, and we expect the original CLR datatypes of the numeric values to be preserved on the recipient end. The problem is that depending on the `FloatParseHandling` option, all numbers are either converted to `double` or to `decimal` after deserialization. Not very surprising knowing that the type information for primitives is not written by the serializer, but we don't mind adding this information to the output in any way (we need no interop, both ends are our own C# programs).

How would you recommend to configure the serializer to preserve the types of numeric values? Ideally (but not necessarily) we would want the smallest possible format like:

```
[
    "hello",
    1.0, // double
    2.0m, // decimal (preferable format, but unfortunately INVALID)
    { "$": "2.0m" }, // less readable, yet still compact enough
    { "type": "Decimal", "value": 2.0 }, // less pretty alternative, but would do as well...
    [
        // nested array or object
    ],
    // etc.
]
```

It seems to be relatively easy to implement a `JsonConverter` which writes such content, but we are stuck at implementing the `ReadJson` overload which only applies custom logic to tokens with 'm' suffix and falls back to the default implementation for anything else.

**EDIT 1:** marked my "preferable format" as INVALID, added a shorter valid alternative, yet the original question - how to implement it in Json.NET - remains open.

Comment: So you want json that is not json? Gratulations.

Comment: Javascript doens't have those datatypes. Json is Javascript...You don't need to put the datatype into the Json, simply make sure the object that is deserialzing the json has the right datatype. FYI Javascript also isn't strongly typed so using an int as a bool (for example) is perfectly valid.

Comment: It isn't really clear what you're asking for - suggestions as to the best format, or a way of implementing *one specific format*.

Comment: Your *preferable format* is **invalid json**! You can't just make a format up...If it's not json, then you can't use a json serializer, you'll have to write your own

Comment: Asking for a way of implementing *any valid format* with Json.NET, especially the reader part.

Comment: then do what Jon has suggested.

Comment: Liam, please elaborate. I integrated Jon's *suggestion on the format*, and (as I said) I see no problem implementing a `JsonConverter` for **writing** such format, yet the **reading** counterpart is somewhat unclear. To me it looks like `ReadJson` method must implement some custom logic for our agreed representation of numbers (also easy) and pass everything else to the default implementation. But I couldn't figure out how do I resort to this fallback with `JsonConverter`.

Comment: You could use something like `TypeWrapper<T>` from [Deserialize specific enum into system.enum in Json.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31351262/deserialize-specific-enum-into-system-enum-in-json-net).

Answer (score 8):

Your preferred format simply isn't JSON. Values in JSON are *only*:

- Numbers (no differentiation between integers and non-integers)
- Strings
- Objects
- Arrays
- Boolean true/false
- `null`

That's it.

So the only way of preserving extra information reliably without breaking JSON would be to serialize the values as objects with the type information, as per your

```
{ "type": "Decimal", "value": 2.0 }
```

example... although in that case I'd make the value a *string* as otherwise you could very easily lose information. (Not every `System.Decimal` is exactly representable as a `System.Double` or vice versa.)

Comment: +1. You could also work with secondary properties. { "price": 2.0, "priceDataType": "decimal" } via coding convention. This is in line with some other .NET subsystems using specially named properties to for example control serialization. But JSON per se has VERY little type information. It is javascript - not a lot of type information there to start with.