# Json.NET serialize List<System.Enum> and back to concrete types

Tags: c#, json, serialization, enums, json.net

I have a `UserProfile` C# class that contains a public list `List<System.Enum> Bonuses;`, whose elements each belong to one of several concrete types of Enums: `BonusUI`, `BonusMusic`, `BonusMode`, etc.

I'm using Json.NET and I wanted to serialize/deserialize the `UserProfile` object. I applied the `[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]` to each concrete enum type, so that they are saved as strings instead of ints. However, this is not enough, as the saved enum values don't even contain their exact type.

```
...
"Bonuses": [
    "MainTheme",
    "ClassicUI",
    "WoodUI",
    "Rampage",
    "SoleSurvivor"
],
...
```

For example, see this error when the deserializer finds BonusMusic.MainTheme (serialized as "MainTheme") inside the list:

> Error converting value "MainTheme" to type 'System.Enum'.

How could I solve this?

Comment: This may be a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31351262/deserialize-specific-enum-into-system-enum-in-json-net

Comment: I see now that it was indeed very similar to that question. It's unfortunate that custom code must be created for this, but I guess it's a somewhat specific case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MainTheme as a simple string cannot be converted to an Enum. You should parse it using something like

```
BonusMusic enum = (BonusMusic)Enum.Parse(typeof(BonusMusic), "MainTheme");
```

Maybe you can implement a JSON custom serializer that could parse the values that come in the Bonuses array

You can check this [JSON.NET Implementing Custom Serialization](http://blog.maskalik.com/asp-net/json-net-implement-custom-serialization/)

Regards.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I knew why the conversion didn't work, but hoped for a simpler solution. :) Because the Bonuses list is a special case and I serialize the enums in other places as ints, I ended up manually converting this specific list instead of adding a custom serializer class (which, truth be told, is also a manual conversion).
The idea is the same: on save, convert the list items into strings like "BonusMusic.MainTheme" and serialize that. On load, convert the string list into the correct enums by splitting on the dot and using `Enum.Parse(Type.GetType(token[0]), token[1]);`