# How to serialize/deserialize a DateTime stored inside an object field using DataContractJsonSerializer?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, polymorphism, datacontractjsonserializer

I use the following class to exchange JSON data over two ASP.NET services :

```
[DataContract]
public class Filter
{
   [DataMember]
   public string Name {get; set;}

   [DataMember]
   public FilterOperator Operator {get; set;}

   [DataMember]
   public object Value {get; set;}    
}
```

Here is the problem : if I set a `DateTime` inside `Value`, it will be deserialized as string :

```
Value = "/Date(1476174483233+0200)/"
```

This is probably because deserializer has no clue to know what was the type of the value when serialized initially :

```
JSON = {"Value":"\/Date(1476174483233+0200)\/"}
```

As explained [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412170.aspx), `DataContractJsonSerializer` supports polymorphism, with the help of the `__type` property.

I have tried to add `[KnownType(typeof(DateTime))]` attribute on the top of the class but it does not help.

However if I set a `Tuple<DateTime>` inside `Value` property (and the appropriate `KnownType` attribute on the class), it works (the value it deserialized properly) :

```
Value = {(10/11/2016 10:49:30 AM)}
```

Inside JSON, `__type` is emited

```
JSON = {
     "Value": {
        "__type" : "TupleOfdateTime:#System",
        "m_Item1" : "\/Date(1476175770028+0200)\/"
     }
}
```

Is there a way to force `DataContractJsonSerializer` to emit proper information to serialize/deserialize `DateTime` properly (which mean I got a `DateTime` after serialization instead of a string) ?

I have try to set `EmitTypeInformation = EmitTypeInformation.Always` in `DataContractJsonSerializerSettings` but it does not help.

Comment: Can you modify the `Filter` class?

Comment: Yes, it can be changed.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `DataContractJsonSerializer` only inserts a polymorphic type hint property `"__type"` for types that correspond to a JSON object - an unordered set of name/value pairs surrounded by `{` and `}`.  If the type maps to anything else (i.e. a JSON array or primitive) then there is no place for a type hint to be inserted.  This restriction is documented in [Stand-Alone JSON Serialization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412170(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_3):

> **Type Hints Apply Only to Complex Types**
>
> There is no way to emit a type hint for non-complex types. For example, if an operation has an Object return type but returns a Circle, the JSON representation can be as shown earlier and the type information is preserved. However, if Uri is returned, the JSON representation is a string and the fact that the string used to represent a Uri is lost. This applies not only to primitive types but also to collections and arrays.

Thus what you will need to do is to modify your `Filter` class to serialized and deserialized a generic surrogate object for its value that encapsulates the value's type information, along the lines the one in [this question for Json.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31351262/deserialize-specific-enum-into-system-enum-in-json-net):

```
[DataContract]
public class Filter
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public FilterOperator Operator { get; set; }

    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public object Value { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    TypedSurrogate TypedValue
    {
        get
        {
            return TypedSurrogate.CreateSurrogate(Value);
        }
        set
        {
            if (value is TypedSurrogate)
                Value = ((TypedSurrogate)value).ObjectValue;
            else
                Value = value;
        }
    }
}

[DataContract]
// Include some well-known primitive types.  Other types can be included at higher levels
[KnownType(typeof(TypedSurrogate<string>))]
[KnownType(typeof(TypedSurrogate<bool>))]
[KnownType(typeof(TypedSurrogate<byte>))]
[KnownType(typeof(TypedSurrogate<sbyte>))]
[KnownType(typeof(TypedSurrogate<char>))]
[KnownType(typeof(TypedSurrogate<short>))]
[KnownType(typeof(TypedSurrogate<ushort>))]
[KnownType(typeof(TypedSurrogate<int>))]
[KnownType(typeof(TypedSurrogate<long>))]
[KnownType(typeof(TypedSurrogate<uint>))]
[KnownType(typeof(TypedSurrogate<ulong>))]
[KnownType(typeof(TypedSurrogate<float>))]
[KnownType(typeof(TypedSurrogate<double>))]
[KnownType(typeof(TypedSurrogate<decimal>))]
[KnownType(typeof(TypedSurrogate<DateTime>))]
[KnownType(typeof(TypedSurrogate<Uri>))]
[KnownType(typeof(TypedSurrogate<Guid>))]
[KnownType(typeof(TypedSurrogate<string[]>))]
public abstract class TypedSurrogate
{
    protected TypedSurrogate() { }

    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public abstract object ObjectValue { get; }

    public static TypedSurrogate CreateSurrogate<T>(T value)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return null;
        var type = value.GetType();
        if (type == typeof(T))
            return new TypedSurrogate<T>(value);
        // Return actual type of subclass
        return (TypedSurrogate)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(TypedSurrogate<>).MakeGenericType(type), value);
    }
}

[DataContract]
public class TypedSurrogate<T> : TypedSurrogate
{
    public TypedSurrogate() : base() { }

    public TypedSurrogate(T value)
        : base()
    {
        this.Value = value;
    }

    public override object ObjectValue { get { return Value; } }

    [DataMember]
    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

Now your JSON will look something like:

```
{
  "TypedValue": {
    "__type": "TypedSurrogateOfdateTime:#Question39973917",
    "Value": "/Date(1476244800000)/"
  }
}
```