# Newtonsoft JSON of Dictionary to list of different Enums

Tags: c#, enums, json.net

I am using Json.NET and I am trying to store a Dictionary mapping from an enum to a list of other enums. The enum Keys are meant to indicate which product, and the value mapped to by that product Key enum is a list of enums that indicate which features are available under it.

I was thinking of having the type of the enum in each value list depend on which product they belong to.

I have the following classes:

```
public enum KeyEnum {
    Key1,
    Key2
}    

public enum ValEnum1 {
    Type1,
    Type2
}    

public enum ValEnum2 {
    Type3,
    Type4,
    Type5,
    Type6
}

class MyClass {
    public Dictionary<KeyEnum, List<Enum>> Data { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to do a

```
var tmp = new MyClass() 
{
    Data = new Dictionary<KeyEnum, List<Enum>>()
    {
        new List<Enum>()
        {
            ValEnum2.Type6
        }
    }   
}

string newdata = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tmp);
var myClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(newdata);
```

I am getting the followering error:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Error converting value 3 to type 'System.Enum'. Path 'Licenses.Audit[0]', line 1, position 160. ---> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int64' to type 'System.Enum'.
```

I'm thinking that I could just convert all of the enum to int instead, but using enums might be better. However, I'm not sure how to properly do this in C#.

Comment: `Enum` is a type in this case. Are you trying to add both ValEnum1 and ValEnum2 to this List? When you are doing inheritence I don't think Enum's are the answer.

Comment: Yeah, I should've mentioned that the value List is going to be either List<ValEnum1> or List<ValEnum2>. I'll edit the post to include that. 

Is there a better approach, or should I do make some baseclass for all 'sub-Enum' to inherit from?

Comment: Looks like this is basically a duplicate of [Deserialize specific enum into system.enum in Json.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31351262).  Or maybe this one is closer: [Deserialize Dictionary<string, object> with enum values in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38336390).  Do either of those answer your question or do you need something more specific?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Newtonsoft serializes `Enum` default to their numeric value. And then it has no idea how to serialize that numeric value back to `Enum`. You can use an attribute on your `Enum` to serialize them to string value (so that your data transfer object is understandable) but to deserialize back to an object you have to implement your own `JsonConverter`.

It's easier to work with more easily serializable data types.

Comment: [Here](http://bytefish.de/blog/enums_json_net/) is an article on how if you wish to go down that road.

Comment: Thanks, I think this applies the best to my usecase since I'm not worried about memory constraints for storing the json with the Enums as strings, and I can still use standard Enums across our applications.